# Where to put Context.xml in a WAR file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I'm porting a app that ran in tomcat to Jboss where it will be deployed as a .WAR file. I have a line of code that looks for a configuration .xml file :

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("cmdAppContext.xml");
```

Now I tried putting it in WEB-INF/classes (After comparing with eclipse generated .WAR file), and also tried the WEB-INF folder as it was referred in that location in the web.xml. However each time I get a NullPointerException. Am I missing anything here?

Please note: I've already seen the similar question in forums which was not resolved

Comment: How are you generating the WAR? Did you make sure that the file was still there after war creation? By putting the file in classes folder, I suspect, its getting cleaned during the build process as that is a output folder?

Comment: Thanks. I am using an Ant build. I added the files explicitly and I can see it in the .WAR file so the files are definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to look into `context.xml` from source code. You should use a `.properties` file to configure your app. .WAR is like a .ZIP file with all sites files inside, so `META-INF` are inside at root folder from .WAR.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case I'm following the below structure          META-INF\
WEB-INF\ 
         classes\Servlet.class                                      lib\*.jar
         web.xml   + cmdAppContext.xml